# Is there a way to clear the terminal screen during a running process?

Tags: command-line

For example, I'm running `tail -f someLogFile`. My screen has gotten full to the point that only the last line is changing. I now want to clear the screen; but the usual <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> doesn't work, just shows me the output `^L`.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd> Won't work as input from keyboard is not accepted, but you can do this:

**Toolbar options of Terminal > Terminal > Reset and clear**

This will do the trick!

Comment: Ah... I'm using guake at the moment which doesn't have a menu bar. But yes this would work on the default terminal.

Comment: Then best option will be to redirect the output i.e. use `$ command > output.txt` This will write all the output in file output.txt

Answer (score 8):

**For Ubuntu (16.04) :**

Go to **Terminal > Preferences > Shortcuts** (tab)

Under Terminal Section set Shortcut key for "Reset" and "Reset and Clear", which is disabled by default.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 2):

<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> unfortunately doesn't work during `tail`.

There are a few things you could do. If you are using the default unity terminal, you can go to Terminal > Reset and clear.

If you are not using a graphic terminal or you're using a different terminal The best thing you could do is run the log into a text file using

```
tail -f /foo/bar > ~/output.txt
```

then you can view it using a text editor. That would let you scroll the file manually.

Answer (score 0):

This will vary depending on what terminal client you are using.

<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F8</kbd> cleared the screen in my cygwin terminal (or right-click and choose "clear" if you are running from Windows).

PuTTY and other terminals probably have similar behavior.